# PHP FTP fwrite() to Windows server not working?

Tags: php, windows, unix, ftp

I am attempting to `fwrite()` via an FTP wrapper from a UNIX-based server to a Windows-based server with PHP. I am connecting successfully, and am able to (for example) create directories. However, I can't seem to write files to the folders! When I look at the directory permissions using an FTP client, I noticed that they are all 0000, and cannot be changed. Apparently, Windows-based servers do not use the same FTP permission system.

So... what's up? What do you recommend? I am able to upload files to the directory using an FTP client, but when I attempt to write files with PHP, nothing happens.

I am at a complete loss as to why this may be occurring. I have confirmed my script works by writing to UNIX-based servers, so that is not a problem. Is it possible that the fact the destination server does not have PHP installed matters? I would not think so, but I'm open to any ideas at this point!

Thank you!

---

**EDIT** - What's really getting me is that I AM able to create directories, so it doesn't make any sense that writing shouldn't be working. On Windows servers, is there some setting that would prevent just the writing of FILES, but not folders?

**EDIT 2** - More research has told me that, though you cannot CHMOD on Windows servers, PHP's CHMOD still somehow does something with the permissions. However, this does not appear to be working for me. Is there a way to change the permissions directly with PHP code, or is this something that has to be done directly on the server, outside of my reach?

Comment: How are you creating the directories, with PHP?

Comment: what ftp client are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to write files that already exist?

Comment: Jim: I have successfully uploaded files using FireFTP.

Comment: Drew010: I've tried both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), and make sure PHP is allowed to write in that directory.

Comment: From the PHP manual: "This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file."